# How to call a method in ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a method defined in `ApplicationController`:

```
def some_checking
  ...
end
```

And I would like to call it from within another controller. E.g.:

```
class OtherController < ApplicationController

  some_checking

  def xxx
  end

end
```

How can I accomplish this? I just can't get into `some_checking`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure on what you want to do. If I've understood you've defined a method on ApplicationController and you want it to be called inside OtherController. To do this you can both use `before_filter` or just call the method from inside the `xxx` method itself.

Take a look to available filters here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

Comment: thanks. i forgot i have to use before_filter in such case. >.<